# Storing JSON object in an attribute of JSON object

Tags: c#, json

How can i store a JSON object in an attribute of JSON object, i mean the value of an attribute of JSON object is another JSON object. I have a DataTable dt, i read data from DataBase and store it in this DataTable.

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Now, i add a column to this DataTable

```
dt.Columns.Add("attributes");
```

Now, i create a JObject and store its value in the "attributes" column for each row of DataTable

```
dynamic attributeValue = new JObject();
attributeValue.type = "Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c";

foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
{
       d["attributes"] = attributeValue;
}
```

Now, i Serialize this DataTable

```
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

The result which i get is

```
{
  "attributes" : "{"type" : "Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c"}",
  "Address__c"   : "Street",
  "AgentID__c"   : "123456",
  "Alert_Status__c"  : "Closed",
  "BusinessUnit__c"  : "INFINITI",
  "Case_Type__c" : "INFINITI Service",
  "City__c"      : "City",
  "ContactId__c"     : "10951",
  "DayTimePhone__c"     : "123456789",
  "DealerCode__c"    : "72067",
  "DealerName__c"    : "Infiniti Of Kansas City",
  "EmailAddress__c"  : "INF@isky.com",
  "EveningPhone__c"  : "123456789",
  "FirstName__c" : "CustomerFirstName",
  "HotAlertType__c"  : "Hot Alert",
  "LastName__c"  : "CustomerSurname",
  "NPS_Score_1__c"   : "0",
  "V01_Alert_Trigger__c"     : "Which of the following best describes your overall service experience?",
  "Field_Open_Date__c"   : "2018-08-05"
}
```

while the result which i want is

```
{
  "attributes" : {"type" : "Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c"},
  "Address__c"   : "Street",
  "AgentID__c"   : "123456",
  "Alert_Status__c"  : "Closed",
  "BusinessUnit__c"  : "INFINITI",
  "Case_Type__c" : "INFINITI Service",
  "City__c"      : "City",
  "ContactId__c"     : "10951",
  "DayTimePhone__c"     : "123456789",
  "DealerCode__c"    : "72067",
  "DealerName__c"    : "Infiniti Of Kansas City",
  "EmailAddress__c"  : "INF@isky.com",
  "EveningPhone__c"  : "123456789",
  "FirstName__c" : "CustomerFirstName",
  "HotAlertType__c"  : "Hot Alert",
  "LastName__c"  : "CustomerSurname",
  "NPS_Score_1__c"   : "0",
  "V01_Alert_Trigger__c"     : "Which of the following best describes your overall service experience?",
  "Field_Open_Date__c"   : "2018-08-05"
}
```

Comment: That's not valid C#. Please provide a [mcve] that compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in your sample code is creating a column in the DataTable without specifying the data type, so the type [defaults to string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Add_System_String_).

```
dt.Columns.Add("attributes");
```

Try using an overload that specifies the type you want, e.g.:

```
dt.Columns.Add("attributes", typeof(object));
```

or maybe:

```
dt.Columns.Add("attributes", typeof(JObject));
```